# php curl equivalent of post with content

Tags: php, post, curl

i have the following get_file_contents code

```
$opts = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/vnd+cbnv+endpoint',
        'content' => $encryptedString
    ));
    $buff = @file_get_contents($URL, false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

How can this be done using curl ?

I am trying something like this

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encryptedString);
$ret = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```

$ret is NULL and it should be a string i echo in the @$URL file

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have problem becouse you foget add context header.

Try this code:

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encryptedString);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: application/vnd+cbnv+endpoint']);
$ret = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```